# Use a for loop over one list but given an output of another list

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to work around a bedgraph file which is a list of lists like the below,

```
{chromosomename, start, end, value}
```

I want to use a for loop to convert it into an array of 0's in all positions except the mentioned positions in which it should be the value mentioned in the 4th element.

```py
a = (1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b = (1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1)

for i in range (10):
    if i in a:
        print (b[i])
    else:
        print (0)
```

when I do the above, the output is b[i] which is the ith element of the list b, but I want the output to be based on the position of the element in a. so for example once i=5 is found, it is the second element in list a so the output should be 1 (not 2). how would I go about doing that?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Neither `a` or `b` are lists. They are tuples. Before you even start, you need to understand the distinction because the former is mutable and the latter isn't. This is fundamental

Comment: I think you want `b[a[b[i]]]` ?

Comment: IIUC: ```print (b[a.index(i)])``` which uses the index function to find the position of the first occurent of i in a.

Comment: The question is unclear, but it seems a mapping of `a` to `b` is needed to look up the required positions: `d = dict(zip(a, b))`. Then the array can be  generated like this: `result = [d.get(i + 1, 0) for i in range(10)]`. So the final result would be this: `[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

We can turn around and loop over elements in `a` while at the same time use the `enumerate()` function to get the indices (positions):

```py
a = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

for index, a_element in enumerate(a):
    if 0 <= a_element < 10:
        print(f"{index=}, {a_element=}, {b[index]=}")
```

Output:

```
index=0, a_element=1, b[index]=1
index=1, a_element=5, b[index]=1
index=2, a_element=6, b[index]=1
index=3, a_element=7, b[index]=2
index=4, a_element=8, b[index]=3
index=5, a_element=9, b[index]=2
```

Notes:

- The enumerate is what you want: it yields both the index and the element
- Once you are happy with the output, you can fix up the `print()` statement to print just `b[index]`